# Prefab doesn't instantiate at the given position

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

The title pretty much sums it up. My enemy prefab is only being instantiated in the Y-axis but the coin prefab is being instantiated how I wanted it, even though they have both the same coordinates.

```
import System.Collections.Generic;

var enemyPrefab : GameObject;
var coinPrefab : GameObject;
public var Coinnumber = 1;
public var Coinnumberside : float = 0.0f;

   function OnTriggerEnter(other: Collider)
     {
    if (other.tag == "Trigger" )
    {       
        var StagePosition : Vector3;
        StagePosition.z = 5.69 + Coinnumber;
        StagePosition.x = 0.0 + Coinnumberside;
        StagePosition.y = 0.4;

        Instantiate(coinPrefab, StagePosition, Quaternion.identity);

    Coinnumber = Coinnumber + Random.Range(5,10); 
    Coinnumberside = Coinnumberside + Random.Range(0.2,-0.4);



        var EnemyPosition : Vector3;
        EnemyPosition.z = 5.69 + Coinnumber;
        EnemyPosition.x = 0.0 + Coinnumberside;
        EnemyPosition.y = 0.4;

        Instantiate(enemyPrefab, EnemyPosition, Quaternion.identity);

    Coinnumber = Coinnumber + Random.Range(5,10); 
    Coinnumberside = Coinnumberside + Random.Range(0.2,-0.4);   




    }
 }
```

Comment: There's something wrong in your question...they don't have the same coordinates. x and z axis depend upon variables that are changed between the 2 assignments, in an aleatory way. Maybe Coinnumber and Coinnumberside have to be changed only at the end of the function?

Comment: Besides what others already pointed, what about you object pivot point, global and local. Are they at the right object point and direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import System.Collections.Generic;

var enemyPrefab : GameObject;
var coinPrefab : GameObject;
public var Coinnumber = 1;
public var Coinnumberside : float = 0.0f;
public var Enemynumber = 1;
public var Enemynumberside : float = 0.0f;

function OnTriggerEnter(other: Collider)
{
    if (other.tag == "Trigger" )
    {       
        var StagePosition : Vector3;
        StagePosition.z = 5.69 + Coinnumber;
        StagePosition.x = 0.0 + Coinnumberside;
        StagePosition.y = 0.4;

        Instantiate(coinPrefab, StagePosition, Quaternion.identity);

        Coinnumber = Coinnumber + Random.Range(5,10); 
        Coinnumberside = Coinnumberside + Random.Range(0.2,-0.4);
    }

    if(other.tag == "Trigger" )
    {
        var EnemyPosition : Vector3;
        EnemyPosition.z = 5.69 + Enemynumber;
        EnemyPosition.x = 0.0 + Enemynumberside;
        EnemyPosition.y = 0.4;

        Instantiate(enemyPrefab, EnemyPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        Enemynumber = Enemynumber + Random.Range(5,10); 
        Enemynumberside = Enemynumberside + Random.Range(0.2,-0.4);

    }
}
```

I'm still not pretty sure why this worked after I seperated them but it did, so I'm putting it as an answer. Thanks for everyone who answered and tried to solve my problem, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood you, you're trying to create an enemy at the same position as you instantiate a coin. The issue, as I can see it, are these lines:

```
Coinnumber = Coinnumber + Random.Range(5,10); 
Coinnumberside = Coinnumberside + Random.Range(0.2,-0.4);
...
EnemyPosition.z = 5.69 + Coinnumber;
EnemyPosition.x = 0.0 + Coinnumberside;
```

You're recalculating the Coinnumber variable right before you set the enemy position. The only unchanging value is the Y coordinates, since you recalculate both Z and X. So, for example, the first time you run this script, your coin will spawn at the position `(5.69f,0.4f,0f)` and then enemyPosition will get random values added to this, so it could (for example) be `(10.69f,0.4f,0.2f)`.

Consider perhaps trying this:

```
var StagePosition : Vector3;
StagePosition.z = 5.69 + Coinnumber;
StagePosition.x = 0.0 + Coinnumberside;
StagePosition.y = 0.4;

Instantiate(coinPrefab, StagePosition, Quaternion.identity);
Instantiate(enemyPrefab, StagePosition, Quaternion.identity);

Coinnumber = Coinnumber + Random.Range(5,10); 
Coinnumberside = Coinnumberside + Random.Range(0.2,-0.4);
```

This will spawn the enemy at the same position as your coin, and then afterward calculate a new position for your next coin & enemy. If however this isn't what you're trying to do, let me know and I'll change my answer.

Comment: Hey Steven. Yes, this is what I'm trying to do. I also tried putting Coinnumber and Coinnumberside in the end, but still, the enemy prefab seems to only instantiate along the Y-axis, upwards and downwards, just like before.

Comment: Have you tried: `Instantiate(enemyPrefab, StagePosition, Quaternion.identity);` ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply but at that time I didn't try this, but when I did, it still didn't work, then I tried using two different IF statements for both instantiations and it worked instantly.
Again, sorry for the late reply.